# linked list initialization in C programming language

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I'm dealing with  C programming language Linked List and I have the underneath MCQ :

We have the following liked list :

```
typedef struct _elt *PElement;
typedef struct _elt {
void *data;
PElement next;
} Element;
```

```
PElement creer_elt_entier(int data) {
     PElement pelt=(PElement)malloc(sizeof(Element));
/* Initialize  data field*/ ;
pelt->next=NULL;

return pelt;
}
```

> Check the correct answer to replace the /* Initialize Field  */ with the appropriate instruction :

☐  pelt->data=data;

☐ pelt->data=&data;

☐ pelt->data=*data;

☐ pelt->data=malloc(sizeof(int));

```
*(pelt->data) = data;
```

☐ pelt->data=malloc(sizeof(int));

```
pelt->data = data;
```

> I replied, by illimitation, the 4th choice , and it's the right answer but I still don't know why it's correct.

Comment: It's the only answer that'll pass through the type-system without assigning a value that becomes invalid upon the functions return (which is what answer 2 does). Regardless of that, it still lacks error-checks (`malloc` may fail) and encourages horrible memory allocation strategies. Storing a pointer to a `malloc`ed in the node instead of storing the `int` there directly is most likely needlessly wasteful. Also, naming a struct `_elt` is downright UB.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. The first option `pelt->data = data;` is incorrect because you cannot assign an integer to a void pointer.
2. The second option `pelt->data = &data;` is incorrect because if you assign a pointer to the parameter *data*, `pelt->data` will be garbage when the function has returned because then the variable pointed to will not exist.
3. The third option `pelt->data = *data;` is incorrect because you cannot dereference a non-pointer variable.
4. The fourth option `pelt->data = malloc(sizeof(int));` and `*(pelt->data) = data;` is correct; a pointer to a heap variable of integer type can be assigned to a void pointer and the heap variable is initialized by first dereferencing it.
5. The fifth option `pelt->data=malloc(sizeof(int));` and `pelt->data = data;` is incorrect because you cannot assign an integer to an integer pointer.